# Inter device near field communication

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ibeacon

I have been working on an app to communicate between devices that come in and out of range.

I originally looked at using iBeacon for this but have since realised android cant act as a beacon so this is no good.

Is there any near field technology which provides proximity updates when a device is in range that work on both android and ios (and allows android to message ios and visa versa) without using bluetooth (as the app needs to be running in the background)?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding the term "near field" as that term is usually used to refer specifically to "Near Field Communication" (NFC), a specific hardware/software protocol.

Some Android devices have NFC hardware. No iOS devices do.

Some Android devices support Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) All iOS devices from the iPhone 4s and iPad 2 forward support BLE.

The iBeacon protocol is built on top of BLE. I understand that Android devices can receive iBeacon signals, but can't act as iBeacon transmitters (at least not yet.)

The only other possibility I can think of would be WiFi Ad Hoc, but as far as I know iOS does not support Ad Hoc (no base station) WiFi connections.

Thus I think your best bet is to do custom development using BLE 4.0. You'll need to define your own peripheral codes and services.

I believe that with the proper permissions, it **IS** possible to both transmit and receive BLE signals from the background in iOS, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can both transmit and receive Bluetooth LE signals from the background in iOS. You have to set (in your Info.plist file), "Required background modes" -> "App shares data using CoreBluetooth" for the phone to act as a bluetooth peripheral while in background mode, and "App communicates using CoreBluetooth" for the phone to act as a central while in background mode.

You can check out this project for an easy way to get Bluetooth LE sharing set up between iOS devices: [SimpleShare - Easy Proximity-based Sharing for iOS](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

I can't help you make the connection to Android, but presumably once you've got your iOS devices to share info via Bluetooth LE you should be able to find a way to set up the Android devices to communicate with them as well. I've heard that there are some bugs with the way Android tries to talk to iOS over Bluetooth LE, but hopefully these will be fixed in a release soon.